# How do you write a single method that requires a password to meet certain requirements?

Tags: java, methods, passwords

Method validatePW:

Does not take any parameters and does not return any.

PW policy: must be at least 4 characters long
           contain at least one two upper case letters
           at least one number.

Throws an exception if PW does not conform to policy.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hopefully you've already tried to write this as per SO guidelines. How far did you get, and where did it go wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to define java methods and catch expections? may need to get familiar with how to define methods in java: [The Java™ Tutorials - Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: "contain at least one two upper case letters at least " what does this phrase mean? at least how many upper case letters?

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length (which in your case is way too low). People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like "Password2018". Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones. NIST published an [official paper](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html) advising against such rules.

Answer (score 1):

This `validatePW` method would probably live in a `User` class that would roughly look something like this:

```
class User {
    private int Id;
    private String Password;
    // ... other class variables, constructor, getters/setters
    public void validatePW() {
        int pwLength = this.Password.length();
        if (pwLength < 4) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password is too short.");
        }
        int upperCase = 0;
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwLength; i++) {
            Character c = this.Password.charAt(i);
            if (c.isUpperCase()) upperCase++;
            if (c.isLowerCase()) lowerCase++;
            if (c.isDigit()) number++;
        }

        if (upperCase == 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password requires at least 1 upper case letter.");
        }

        if (lowerCase == 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password requires at least 1 lower case letter.");
        }

        if (number == 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password requires at least 1 number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider reading [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), specifically [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and the chapter on [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) as these are basics you should be familiar to complete this assignment.

There are many ways to complete this task, this is only one example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;


public class Q53733706 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();
        validatePW(password);
    }

    // Method validatePW:
    static void validatePW(String p){
        int upperCase = 0;
        int isDigit = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < p.length(); k++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(p.charAt(k))) isDigit++;
            if (Character.isUpperCase(p.charAt(k))) upperCase++;
        }

        if ((p.length() < 4) || (upperCase < 1) || (isDigit < 1)){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid password.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Valid password.");
        }
    }    
}
```

Adjust the conditional checks to meet your particular "PW policy" as they are unclear as currently stated in the question.